# Check if fields editable in RestAPI

Tags: rest-api, fields

I've seen one similar question, but it didn't help me to find required solution.The thing is - I acquired all field of Leads object through RestAPI, but I need to check if those fields are available and can be edited, because I retrieved 50 fields and only 46 are available of them when I looked through user interface. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sObject Describe resource to determine if a field is editable.

Here is an example of a describe call from the docs:

```
https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/Account/describe/ -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_describe.htm) are the docs.

In the body of the response, you'll see something like this:

```
{
"name" : "Account",
"fields" : 
[ 
    {  
        "length" : 18,  
        "name" : "Id",  
        "type" : "id",  
        "defaultValue" : {    "value" : null  },  
        "updateable" : false,  
        "label" : "Account ID",  
        ...
    },
```

You are looking for the `updateable` key. If it's false, you can't edit this field.

Comment: Thanks for response, I did it like that, but for some bad assumptions and bad linq couldn't find this easy answer. Thank you, for ensuring me